# Why won't Ansible mount Vagrant remote NFS share

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

My Ansible playbook is raising an error when I try to execute the mount module:

```
Error mounting 192.168.33.1:/Users/me/playbooks/site1/website: mount.nfs: remote share not in 'host:dir' format
```

The code directory is mounted:

```
$ vagrant ssh -c "mount | grep http"
192.168.33.1:/Users/me/playbooks/site1/website on /srv/http/site1.com type nfs (...)
```

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.synced_folder "website/", "/srv/http/site1.com", nfs: true
end
```

Ansible playbook:

```
- name: Remount code directory
  hosts: web
  sudo: True
  tasks:
    - name: unmount website
      mount:
        name: /srv/http/site1.com
        src: srv_http_site1.com
        fstype: nfs
        state: unmounted
    - name: remount website
      mount: 
        name="192.168.33.1:/Users/me/playbooks/site1/website"
        src="srv_http_site1.com" 
        fstype=nfs 
        state=mounted
```

I'm running NFS v3:

```
$ sudo nfsstat | grep nfs  # => Client nfs v3
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.  The unmount task will unmount the filesystem but the following mount tasks fails.  The mount(8) man page says "device may look like knuth.cwi.nl:/dir".  The nfs(5) man page says that server host names can be "a dotted quad IPv4 address".  I tried adding the following line to my /etc/hosts file:

```
laptop    192.168.33.1
```

and then replacing the mount name argument "192.168.33.1" with "laptop" but that didn't fix it either.  Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your hosts file entry is backward. It should be `192.168.33.1  laptop`.

Comment: Thanks, good catch.  But now I'm getting a "mount... is not a block device error" so I'll have to return to this problem if/after I resolve that one.

Comment: I'm also wondering why you're trying to mount/unmount a directory on your host machine that is already set up as a synced folder with Vagrant. The Ansible playbook seems redundant, but I could be missing something.

Comment: The reason is that I'd like shared folder to be owned by the same group who'll own it on my prod server.  But I can't assign that ownership when Vagrant creates the synced folder since the group doesn't exist. I could create the group and remount it in a provision script but then I'd have to always add --provision when doing ups and reloads. If I use provision's "run: always", then I'd have to remember to do --no-provision if I don't want it to run.  This is ugly so I thought I'd try doing it in my playbook but clearly that's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a couple of issues with your Ansible playbook. The last part is not valid YAML, but more importantly the `name` and `src` in your mounts are reversed. The docs state that "[`src` is device to be mounted on name](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mount_module.html#options)". Also the name should be the path to the mount point. Here's the playbook with those issues resolved...

```
- name: Remount code directory
  hosts: web
  sudo: True
  tasks:
    - name: unmount website
      mount:
        name: /srv/http/site1.com
        src: 192.168.33.1:/Users/me/playbooks/site1/website
        fstype: nfs
        state: unmounted
    - name: remount website
      mount:
        name: /srv/http/site1.com
        src: 192.168.33.1:/Users/me/playbooks/site1/website
        fstype: nfs
        state: mounted
```

If you make these changes and comment out the `synced_folder` in your Vagrantfile, I think it will work in the way that you want.