# ansible mount module can't find special device

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-18.04, mount

I'm trying to get ansible to mount my attached and formatted hard drive located under `/dev/vdb/` to `/data`. This is the playbook section:

```
---
- name: setup dada2 
  hosts: tnt
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks: 
    - name: Create the file system
      filesystem:
        fstype: ext4
        dev: /dev/vdb

    - name: Mount the created filesystem
      mount:
        path: /data
        src: /dev/vdb/
        fstype:  ext4
        state: mounted

    - name: Make /data available for everyone
      file:
        path: /data
        state: directory
        mode: 0775
```

However, I get the error message:

```
TASK [Mount the created filesystem] ********************************************
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error mounting /data: mount: /data: special device /dev/vdb/ does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory).\n"}
```

but `/dev/vdb` does exist and running `sudo mount /dev/vdb /data` works fine. Any ideas what could be the reason for this? I have no experience with `/etc/fstab`, but the name occured often so I had a look into it. It says:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 0
LABEL=UEFI      /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0 0
/dev/vdb/ /data ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Any ideas on this one?

EDIT:

A similar error was described here: [Error in Mount Module in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449311/error-in-mount-module-in-ansible), but I set the fstype as suggested and I would not know what entry I would have to add to fstab and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the trailing slash in `/dev/vdb/`

```
- name: Mount the created filesystem
  mount:
    path: /data
    src: /dev/vdb/
    fstype:  ext4
    state: mounted
```

Correct

```
- name: Mount the created filesystem
  mount:
    path: /data
    src: /dev/vdb
    fstype:  ext4
    state: mounted
```

Remove the line from /etc/fstab manually

```
/dev/vdb/ /data ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Comment: I removed the line from fstab and rerun the playbook without the trailing `/`, it worked perfect! Thank you